# ES2015 (ES6) sub destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have question regarding destructuring in Javascript, say for example I have this object structure:

```
let obj = { 
    subObj: {
        id: 123,
        otherProp: 'value'      
    }
};
```

Is this destructuring pattern even possible:

```
let { subObj: { id } } = obj

let someId = id;
let otherObj = subObj //this is not working
```

I would like to grab the sub object and a property within the sub object in one operation. I've had a look on this resource [2ality](http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html) but cant to find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to grab the sub object and a property within the sub object in one operation

You can do that like this:

```
let {subObj : {id}, subObj} = obj;
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^
//         \           \----- grabs subObj
//          \---------------- grabs id
```

The other order is fine too:

```
let {subObj, subObj : {id}} = obj;
//   ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//      \          \--------- grabs id
//       \------------------- grabs subObj
```

Example:

```js
let obj = {
  subObj: {
    id: 123,
    otherProp: 'value'
  }
};
// Grabs subObj ----vvvvvv
let {subObj : {id}, subObj} = obj;
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^---grabs id
console.log(subObj);
console.log(id);
```